# go get gopkg.in/gomail.v1 cannot get gomail module

Tags: go

I am trying to get gomail via gopkg.in/gomail.v1 but my connection just stays hanging. In other words, on my console, when I type:

```
[developer@machine gocode]$ go get gopkg.in/gomail.v1
```

I get nothing
However in the /gocode/src/gopkg.in directory, I see a directory named gomail.v1 with nothing inside..

Comment: I am using CentOS 6.5, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will help others. I spent almost 3 hours figuring this out. Apparently,

```
[developer@machine gocode]$ go get gopkg.in/wantedpackage
```

will not not work with git version < 1.7.9.5. 
The trick is to upgrade your git version. I upgraded my git version to 1.7.12.4 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

`go get` does not not display anything while downloading and installing libraries. So as long as you are connected to the internet just wait. If there are troubles connecting to the server it will display an error.

Depending on your platform: Check if you have installed `git` and `hg`.

Comment: yes I have git(version 1.7.1) and mercurial(version 1.4) installed. I have been waiting for almost 30 minutes but nothing happen. I have to use ctrl-c to exit the process. Does it take longer than 30 minutes? I have used go get github.com/etc/etc without a problem.

Comment: @WarrenV Thats indeed weird and way to long.

Comment: @WarrenV it tried on my machine and with an tethered 3G connections and its installed in just under a minute.

Comment: I posted my solution. Upgrading my git version resolved my issue. Thanks for trying to help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @WarrenV Nice find. It would be interesting what exactly changed between the two git versions.